# Django models uppercase

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

i'm a Django site building beginner, i wanna convert an input of my models to uppercase before it's registered in the db. so it's shows in uppercase in administration site, as also in the db.

Comment: How do you current store data in the database?

Comment: i store 'em with django admin site by creating new objects...i found the solution alredy...thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create a class within a function that returns the entry value in uppercase:

```
class Name(models.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Name, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        return str(value).upper()
```

then define the attribute of your model with the class you've created earlier:

```
class Person(modesl.Model):
    name = Name(
            validators=[name_regex],
            max_length=255, 
            blank= False, 
            verbose_name='Prénom',
            )
```